# ReactJS Relay Modern: which router to choose?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, relayjs, relaymodern

I'm building a large SaaS CRUD application using ReactJs. There is a classic navigation need for the whole application, something like the following pattern for every object:

```
Item list -> Item detail -> Item edit/delete
    |------> Item create
```

For every type of object, you can list then or create a new one. In the listing, you can see details, edit or delete an item. The application will have a top navigation menu that you move you to the object type chosen listing.

In terms of Relay, every object type will hold its query. The detailsview will work with the query fragments.

Seems that a simple router would be enough, but I don't want to start using old stuff or deprecated code.

As far as I understood, Relay Modern cannot work with React Router V4, although I've seen questions regarding ways to use React Router V4 with Relay Modern. So:

a) Can I use RRV4 for that type of application ? Will I have a problem with that?

b) If not, should I go for RRV3 or Found ? Which one is recommended ?

Answer (score 2):

You may consider [found](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found) and [found-relay](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found-relay). I am evaluating them now and appreciate that found explicitly addresses the problem of request waterfalls with static routes. Found Relay supports Relay Modern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why RRV4 wouldn't work with Relay, take whichever router you prefer. RRV4 seems like a good choice.

Comment: The official Relay doc says that it is incompatible on nested routes. See [this documentation page](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/routing.html#react-router-https-reacttraining-com-react-router)

Comment: @Mendes effectively ! Sorry about that